# How to calculate $\left|\langle \psi,(1j)\rangle \right|$ where $\psi=(12 \cdots n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

How to calculate $\left|\langle\psi,(1j)\rangle\right| $ where $ \psi=(12 \cdots n).$

I am considering which $j$ makes $\langle\psi,(1j)\rangle=S_{n}.$One of my friends told me that I can even calculate $\left|\langle\psi,(1j)\rangle\right|$.But I have no idea where to start.Any help will be thanked.

Comment: Use \langle and \rangle instead of < and > - these should be mostly used for inequalities.

Comment: Different $j$ will cause different value. You may try $(1234)$ with $(12)$ and $(13)$

Comment: Here are some hints. If $j-1$ is coprime to $n$, then $\psi^{j-1}$ is an $n$-cycle, and so $S_n = \langle \psi^{j-1},(1,j) \rangle =\langle \psi,(1,j) \rangle$. Otherwise $\psi$ and $(1,j)$ both preserve a proper partition of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, so they do not generate $S_n$.